# Python: Write array to file row by row

Tags: python, file, numpy, string-formatting

I have a file with the content of

```
18
21
24
27
30
```

And  the array of

```
[[ 1  6 11]
 [ 2  7 12]
 [ 3  8 13]
 [ 4  9 14]
 [ 5 10 15]]
```

How can I write this array to file so that each row will be corresponding with the appropriate lines such as it becomes something like this:

```
18    1  6 11
21    2  7 12
24    3  8 13
27    4  9 14
30    5 10 15
```

I have used this code, but it does not write the code as I want. The code:

```
import numpy as np

    ourlist = []
    for i in range(1, 16):
        ourlist.append(i)


    mydata = np.matrix([ourlist])
    array_from_list=(mydata.reshape(3, 5))
    x_transpose = (np.transpose(array_from_list))   # the array above

    with open('5rows.txt','a') as f:                #the file containing numbers
     for elements in x_transpose:
         f.write(str(elements))
         f.write('\n')
```

It instead writes elements to the end of line. If possible, could you tell me how I can do this, please ? I really appreciate your help !

Comment: Have you tried using a dataframe? It might make things easier for you.

Comment: So the first column in the file is the sum of the row. Is this not put there by you? My answer assumes a horizontal append is required, but maybe you are first writing the sums, then trying to write the matrix next to it. That would not be a good way to go about that. Maybe I'm being presumptuous, but I thought I should be curious for your future benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code bellow might solve your problem, although it is not very performatic. You may be able to improve the solution to better fit your needs.

```
import numpy as np

ourlist = []

for i in range(1, 16):
    ourlist.append(i)


mydata = np.matrix([ourlist])
array_from_list=(mydata.reshape(3, 5))
x_transpose = (np.transpose(array_from_list))

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        f.write(str(int(line)) + "  " + str(x_transpose[i])[1:-1][1:-1] + "\n")
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.savetxt` writes a csv file.  In this case the trick is to assemble your two arrays/lists into a composite array, and then format it as you want:

```
In [100]: mydata = np.arange(1,16).reshape(3,5)
In [101]: mydata
Out[101]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [102]: mydata = np.arange(1,16).reshape(3,5).T
In [103]: mydata
Out[103]: 
array([[ 1,  6, 11],
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14],
       [ 5, 10, 15]])
In [104]: elements = np.arange(18,31,3)
In [105]: elements
Out[105]: array([18, 21, 24, 27, 30])
In [106]: arr = np.column_stack((elements, mydata))
In [107]: arr
Out[107]: 
array([[18,  1,  6, 11],
       [21,  2,  7, 12],
       [24,  3,  8, 13],
       [27,  4,  9, 14],
       [30,  5, 10, 15]])
In [108]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, fmt='%2d   %3d %3d %3d')
In [109]: cat test.txt
18     1   6  11
21     2   7  12
24     3   8  13
27     4   9  14
30     5  10  15
```

Equivalently I could `zip` to two arrays; combine `row` values into one tuple, and format that:

```
In [112]: for e, d in zip(elements, mydata):
     ...:     ed = (e,)+tuple(d)
     ...:     print('%2d   %3d %3d %3d'%ed)
              # print(('%d  '%e) + ' '.join(['%3d']*3)%tuple(d))
     ...:     
18     1   6  11
21     2   7  12
24     3   8  13
27     4   9  14
30     5  10  15
```

I'm using `print` but you could switch that to file write.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what 'append' means. When you are appending data to a file, that means vertical append: adding content to the end of the file. If you want to do a horizontal append you first will have to read the data in and then write everything back.

```
import numpy as np

mydata = np.matrix(list(range(1, 16)))
array_from_list=(mydata.reshape(3, 5))
x_transpose = (np.transpose(array_from_list))   # the array above

with open('5rows.txt','r') as f:
    lines = list(f)
with open('5rows.txt','w') as f:
    for existing, new in zip(lines[:16], x_transpose):
        f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(existing, '\t'.join(new)))
```